# Upload multiple files via ajax from an HTML file input

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, uploads

I'm trying to upload files from a multiple file upload HTML input via ajax on a WordPress site but I keep getting a 400 error and I'm not sure why. My code is based on [this tutorial](https://carlofontanos.com/ajax-multi-file-upload-in-wordpress-front-end/).

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(){

  var fd = new FormData();
  var files_data = $(this); // The <input type="file" /> field

  // Loop through each data and create an array file[] containing our files data.
  $.each($(files_data), function(i, obj) {
      $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
          fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);
      })
  });

  fd.append('action', 'file_upload');

  fd.append('nonce', $('#file_upload_nonce').val());

  fd.append('application_id', $(this).closest('.application_question').attr('data-application-id'));

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
  });

});
```

PHP:

```
function file_upload(){
  // Check the nonce first
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'file_upload' ) ) {
    echo 'Security validation failed.';
  } else {

    $application_id = $_POST['application_id'];

    foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name ) {

      move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], '/wp-content/supporting-evidence/' . $application_id . '/' . $_FILES["files"]["name"][$f] );

    }

  }
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_file_upload','file_upload');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you put your PHP code, is it in the theme functions file? Were you logged-in when you tried your form?

Comment: The PHP is within a plugin file and I was logged in when I tested the form (it's designed to only be accessed by logged in users). EDIT: You've just helped me realise that I wasn't `@include`ing the PHP file (doh!) I'm not getting the 400 error now, but the files aren't being uploaded.

Comment: Have you checked, via the browser console, whether the AJAX request is being sent properly? If yes, try adding a `echo 'it works';` after the `foreach` loop in your PHP function, then see if the AJAX *response* includes that `it works` text.

Comment: I can see in the comments you are no longer getting the 400 error - did you find a solution? Can you check if you `var_dump($_FILES)` in your php file if there are any files being sent over ? Have you included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute on the form which you are submitting? I can see you are using the application id to organise your folders within supporting evidence - do you need to create the directory before uploading the file to that location using `mkdir()` function i.e. if(!is_dir('/wp-content/supporting-evidence/'.$application_id)) { mkdir('/wp-content/supporting-ev

Comment: @AJT can you leave that you didn't `include` the file as an answer? It's not obvious that you found the solution, the site doesn't know this and people don't always leave comments

Answer (score 0):

**It's because you're logged out and the code does not handle that**

*There is also a major security hole in the code, scroll down to see the details*

HTTP 400 and a `0` is what `admin-ajax.php` returns when it cannot find a handler for your AJAX request.

*Note that if you had used the modern REST API instead of the legacy `admin-ajax.php` API it would have told you this in plaintext human readable language and a 404 like this:*

```json
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

*It would also have responded with a 403 forbidden if you'd made the same mistake, which is much harder to make when using AJAX with a REST API endpoint*

If we look at the tutorial we can see where it adds the AJAX handler action:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_cvf_upload_files', 'cvf_upload_files');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cvf_upload_files', 'cvf_upload_files'); // Allow front-end submission
```

**But**, if we look at the code in your question:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_file_upload','file_upload');
```

Your code has 1 action, the tutorial has 2. You're missing the `wp_ajax_nopriv_` version.

Overrall, keep in mind this is an 8 year old tutorial from 2015, and you shouldn't follow just a single tutorial when researching things. The official WordPress developer docs explain this much better, *and since that tutorial was written a new modern API for AJAX called the REST API was written*.

### Further Notes

- you never checked that `move_uploaded_file` worked or not, it returns a `false` value if it failed, you need to check for this or it will fail silently and you'll be scratching your head trying to figure out why files are missing
- it needs to create the folder!
- you should not assume the location of the upload folder, the tutorial you shared uses `wp_upload_dir()` instead of assuming `/wp-content/uploads` to do this
- What if `$_POST['application_id']` contained something malicious? e.g. `../`? or `myapplicationID/and/this/is/a/subfolder`?
- the AJAX happens every time the file input changes, which means if I accidentally pick the wrong file, it's instantly uploaded and I can't get it back! What if I picked something confidential by accident that was next to it and now we're both in trouble? Or if I select the same file 5 times, now there are 5 copies on your server. What if I accidentally select a 24GB blueray backup file?

  - the tutorial also has a check for this, but your code does not

#### A Major Security Problem In The Code

- **There is no validation on the files, I could use this to upload and run PHP files!!!!**

  - the tutorial you're following uses the `wp_check_filetype` function to do this
  - I could use your form to submit PHP files that give me total control over your website then just visit `example.com/wp-content/supporting-evidence/myapplicationID/hacksite.php`, **this is very dangerous!**
  - at a minimum check the file extensions, WordPress has functions for checking valid filetypes

Comment: Actually, he was logged-in.. it's just his AJAX action wasn't registered, because he forgot to `include` the PHP file containing his `add_action()` code. He also said that the form was meant for logged-in users only.. But as for the rest in your answer, e.g. using the REST API, or a WordPress-specific function for handling the uploads, I totally agree :)